# How can I convert my string to type for enums?

Tags: javascript, enums, typeconverter

For example I have enumtype like: "SampleEnum"

```
SampleEnum: {
        Day: 0,
        Week: 1,
        Month: 2
    },
```

But for one spesific stuff, it comes me as string like "SampleEnum"
I have to convert it ------> type directly it should be SampleEnum so I can use
Enums.SampleEnum. I need this. How can I do ??

Comment: it should not come to your as string, but if you insist to take this path, just consider as you suggested having a map Enums = {SampleEnumKEY:SampleEnum} so you can get your SampleEnum from the map by referring to its key (here would be Enums.SampleEnumKEY)

Comment: I put column type as Enum for mygrid. So it comes as string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SampleEnum= {
    Day: 0,
    Week: 1,
    Month: 2
}

var str="SampleEnum";
```

You can access SampleEnum using window object of the browser like

```
window[str]
```